# SSAS Tabular model error - exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation upon restart

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas, cube, ssas-2012

We are using tabular model in SSAS. As a part of the daily cube processing(Process Full), there is step in ETL, which restarts the analysis service on the cube server(to clear the memory). Here we face an *intermittent* issue. The analysis service stops but does not turn back up sometimes(2 times out of 5). The error we receive is

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

So someone has to log in to the server and manually start the service. As I mentioned, this error does not occur every day.

**Note**

We have NLB on the two SSAS nodes(2 physical load balancing SSAS servers) which are synced every day during cube processing. The error above takes place on either one of them.

**Code which restarts SSAS**

```
public void Main()
        {
            Process[] processArray = Process.GetProcessesByName("MSSQLServerOLAPService", Dts.Variables["ProcessServerName"].Value.ToString());
            foreach (Process process in processArray) //kill all instances of the SSAS process
            {
                process.Kill();
                process.WaitForExit(); //wait for the process to be killed
            }

            ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MSSQLServerOLAPService", Dts.Variables["ProcessServerName"].Value.ToString());
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped && service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) //check to make sure the killed process resulted in a stopped service
            {
                service.Stop();
            }
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            service.Start(); //restart the SSAS service
            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["ServiceRestartDurationSeconds"].Value.ToString()) * 500);
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

            ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["AW Cube Process"];
            string connectionString = cm.ConnectionString.ToString();
            AdomdConnection adomdConn = new AdomdConnection(connectionString);
            adomdConn.Open(); //this kick starts loading the Tabular Model data into memory

            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["ServiceRestartDurationSeconds"].Value.ToString()) * 500);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

**Questions**

1) What could be possible reasons for this error?

2) The only reason analysis service is restarted is to clear the memory of old model and reload the tabular model into memory. But this is something we want to avoid if possible. Does any better way or workaround exist which could replace the restart of analysis service?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks!

Comment: My assumption is that this occasionally happens due to the time involved in turning off or turning back on the service. However I must agree with @billinkc in that I don't understand what you think you're gaining by restarting the service. This seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Restarting SSAS clears the memory cache thus leading to much reduced processing times. @billinkc - Which log are you talking about? I have checked the SQL log and I see this error message. I ran a trace on the cube server on both the nodes but didn't find anything. There is nothing in event log as well. Any other log you talking about specifically? Will post the script which restarts the service soon, but I don't think there is an issue there, as it is an intermittent issue.

Comment: @Zane - If this is a timeout issue, where can the timeout value be set? We have a SQL delay step in ETL just after this step, which waits for 300 seconds for the service to be back up. I tested and found 300 seconds to be more than enough.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti is your wait after you've stopped the service? My assumption is your calling it to start to quickly. Although this is all a guess since you haven't posted any of the code you're using. Also don't clear the cache in the first place. SSAS can handle that all on it's own.

Comment: Eeegads man you're killing the process. This is even worse than I thought. Why not just clear the cache or better yet just leave it alone and let it do it's thing?

Comment: @billinkc - Have tried. Doesn't have any significant effect. Moreover, it's meant for MDM on which it  works, but not on tabular model. Check this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230974.aspx) article.

Comment: @Zane - No. The delay(Execute SQL task) is after the completion of the script task, which basically gives a window to SSAS to restart comfortably. As I stated, it improves processing time by a lot. I think you are missing the point here. There is no issue with the _stopping_ of the service as that happens successfully every time. It's the _starting_ of the service that fails. Clearing cache doesn't have any significant impact. See my comment above.

Comment: I'm not saying there is an issue with stopping the service. It's an issue with how you're stopping the service that could be causing the error that you are seeing. Either way I'm out good luck.